# How to create divi custom module

Tags: wordpress, plugins, divi

Is any one know how to create divi custom module using wordpress plugin.
I want to develop my own custom module.

i want to create woocommerce product slider in divi theme using divi builder which can show product price, product image, product sku and  cart button in slider